# Share Authentication Cookie between .net 4x and .net 5 app - Accessing the User ClaimsPrinciple

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

I have followed the setup suggested in this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#share-authentication-cookies-between-aspnet-4x-and-aspnet-core-apps

I set the authentication cookie by logging in to the .net 4x App and then try and access a page class that is guarded by the `[Authorize]` attibute on the .net 5 core app. This fails and I am directed back to the login page. If I remove the `[Authorize]` attribute and access and decrypt the shared Authentication cookie I can see the user and claims that were created by the .net 4x app in the AuthenticationTicket (see code below) - but when trying to access the ClaimsPrincipal User in the page. this User does not have any of the details as per the cookie. The `var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;` is always null.

```
var dataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\keyring"));         
            var cookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();
            var cookie = cookieManager.GetRequestCookie(HttpContext, ".AspNetCore.SharedCookie");
            var dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector
("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Identity.Application", "v2");
            //Get teh decrypted cookies as a Authentication Ticket
            TicketDataFormat ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookie);

            var user =  _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
```

Below is the configureservices code in the startup.cs file in the .net 5 application

```
....

 services.AddDbContext<RosterDBContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("databaseconnection")
                    , sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(120)
                    );
                options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            });

            services.AddIdentity<RosterUser, RosterRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RosterDBContext>();
                

            services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>
                (
                    options => { 
                        options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);                        
                    }
                );

            services.AddDataProtection()
                 .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\keyring"));               

            services.AddAuthentication("Identity.Application")
                .AddCookie(config =>
                {
                    config.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.SharedCookie";
                    config.Cookie.Path = "/";
                });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {              
                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login/";                   

            });
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddRazorPages();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who sees this - I was able to solve this issue. I removed these lines and replaced `services.AddIdentity<RosterUser, RosterRole>() .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RosterDBContext>();`

with the following:

`services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddSignInManager() .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RosterDbContext>();`

I removed my own identity user to eliminate any issues if any were because of the user and used the **AddIdentityCore** method rather than **AddIdentity** . This stopped the error I kept getting stating the the "***Scheme already exists: Identity.Application***" because of this line `.AddCookie("Identity.Application"`.

Also i added the app name to both applications:
.net 4x `,(builder) => { builder.SetApplicationName("cms-app"); })` and in the .net core app  `.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\keyring")) .SetApplicationName("cms-app");`